# How to solve this error in Activating WP Plugin?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to activate this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/thethe-layout-grid/ after installing it 
but I got this error : Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal error.

how can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

- asking in the WordPress plugin's [support page](http://wordpress.org/tags/thethe-layout-grid?forum_id=10#postform)
- disabling all other plugins and try to activate TheThe plugin, if it works go enabling the others one by one till you find the conflict
- making sure you're using the minimun required WP version by the plugin (*Requires at least: 3.0*)
- checking your server error log to see if there's a clue there